# how to download web buffers in android?

Tags: android, spring, download

I'm developping in galaxy note 10.1

the download action start java spring action.

this download action is well proceed in PC, browser in mobile device

the problem is galaxy note 10.1 built-in browser

this browser's userAgent is

"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; ko-kr; SHW-M480W Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30"

and android's download method is

mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener(){
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String sUserAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
                URL urls = null;
                String fileUrl = "";
                String mPath = "";
                Log.v("sUserAgent", sUserAgent);

```
            String condition[] = contentDisposition.split("=");
            String x = condition[1];
            Log.d("test",x);
            try {
                fileUrl = URLDecoder.decode(x, "UTF-8");
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                urls = new URL(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String fileName[] = url.split("/");
            Log.d("test", url);
            try {
                HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)urls.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.connect();
                mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/";

                String chkPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/"+fileUrl;
                File chkFile = new File(chkPath);
                if(chkFile.exists() == true){}
                else {
                    File f = new File(mPath);
                    f.mkdirs();
                    File OutputFile = new File(f, fileUrl);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(OutputFile);
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    byte[]buffer = new byte[24576];
                    int len1 = 0;

                    while((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    fos.close();
                    is.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DOWNLOAD COMPLETED", 0).show();
            File files = new File(mPath+fileUrl);
            Log.e("msg",mPath+fileUrl+"");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String mimes = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.length()-3, fileUrl.length());
            if(mimes.equals("hwp")) {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(files), "application/x-hwp");
            } else {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(files), "application/"+mimes);
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }   
    });
```

the spring download action is

String mimetype = "application/x-msdownload";

```
                response.setContentType(mimetype);
                response.setHeader("fileName", fvo.getFileStreCours()+fvo.getStreFileNm());
                setDisposition(fvo.getOrignlFileNm(), request, response);
                response.setContentLength(fSize);

                BufferedInputStream in = null;
                BufferedOutputStream out = null;

                try {
                    in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(uFile));
                    out = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

                    FileCopyUtils.copy(in, out);
                    out.flush();
                    response.flushBuffer();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    // Connection reset by peer: socket write error
                    log.debug("IGNORED: " + ex.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    if (in != null) {
                        try {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                            log.debug("IGNORED: " + ignore.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    if (out != null) {
                        try {
                            out.close();
                        } catch (Exception ignore) {
                            log.debug("IGNORED: " + ignore.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

this file is downloading from NAS

but android was not access web's response buffer

in android, maked 0 byte file.

how to access buffer and download file in web's response buffer?

ps. web service not allow open url, so I can't use redirect